# React component for round slider with multiple range selection

Tags: reactjs, slider, rc-slider

I need to implement a round slider in which we can select multiple ranges in same slider(attaching image below for the reference of how would it look like). I have found this great library [rc-slider](https://github.com/schrodinger/rc-slider)  which supports selection of multiple ranges in single slider, but I could see examples for only horizontal and vertical slider and I couldn't find anywhere in the docs that it supports multiple shapes of slider. So, is there any way to implement round slider with this rc-slider or any react component library that you know of which supports round shape and multiple range selections?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether still you need this, but I believe the below solution will solve this requirement.

This can be customized through the [roundSlider](https://roundsliderui.com/) plugin. below I have updated the POC sample of your requirement. Check the demo:

### [**`DEMO`**](https://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/4evqx9du/)

[image: round slider with multiple range selection]

> **Note:** This can be integrated into React as well.

#### Edited:

Swathi, based on your comments you can add any number of handles with roundSlider. Also you can customize the each handle behaviour. Through the `beforeValueChange` event you can decide all the handle behaviour.

Also if you want the range for each handle, then you can add your custom range on top of the slider path corresponding to each handle.

Check the below updated demo:

### [**`DEMO 1`**](https://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/sj1tcqo8/)

[image: round slider with multiple handles and ranges]

Comment: Hi Soundar, thanks a lot for you answer. I have checked out roundSlider, as far as I remember roundSlider gives ability select one range, but my requirement is to be able to select multiple ranges. For example: I wanted 3 handles with each of them having a range, 1-30, 31-50, 51-100. When I was doing a POC with roundSlider, was not able to do it easily. Tried some customisation, it didn't fit all cases. Does your POC sample supports 3 handles with each having range?

Comment: @Swathi I have updated the answer based on your comments, still you can do all kind of customizations.